# How to overlay two geom_bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to overlay 2 the bars from `geom_bar` derived from 2 separate data.frames.

```
dEQ
   lab perc
1  lmP 55.9
2  lmN 21.8
3   Nt  0.6
4 expG  5.6
5 expD  0.0
6 prbN 11.2
7 prbP  5.0
```

and

```
LMD
   lab perc
1  lmP 16.8
2  lmN  8.9
3   Nt  0.0
4 expG  0.0
5 expD  0.0
6 prbN  0.0
7 prbP  0.0
```

The first plot is:

```
p <- ggplot(dEQ, aes(lab, perc)) + 
     xlab(xlabel) + ylab(ylabel) +
     geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="blue", fill="darkblue")  + 
     geom_text(aes(vecX, vecYEQ+1.5, label=vecYlbEQ), data=dEQ, size=8.5)  + 
     theme_bw() +
     opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(size = 20, face = "bold", colour = "black")) +
     opts(axis.text.y = theme_text(size = 20, face = "bold", colour = "black")) +
     coord_flip() + 
     scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60),
                        labels=c("0","","20","","40","","60"), 
                        limits = c(0, 64), expand = c(0,0))
print(p)
```

but I want to overplot with another `geom_bar` from data.frame `LMD`

```
ggplot(LMD, aes(lab, perc)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="blue", fill="red", add=T)
```

and I want to have a legend.

Comment: There is any valid reason to not combine the two datasets before the ggplot command?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

here is an example:

```
p <- ggplot(NULL, aes(lab, perc)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = "dEQ"), data = dEQ, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = "LMD"), data = LMD, alpha = 0.5)
p
```

[image]

but I recommend to `rbind` them and plot it by dodging:

```
dEQ$name <- "dEQ"
LMD$name <- "LMD"
d <- rbind(dEQ, LMD)
p <- ggplot(d, aes(lab, perc, fill = name)) + geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: can you move the dodged data above each other? like a negative distance between the two bar types?

Comment: @PeterPan You can do that with `position = "stack"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, both solutions give me an error code:

Answer (score 2):

Though the answer is not directly the requirement of OP, but as this question is linked to many subsequent questions on SO that have been closed by giving the link of this question, I am proposing a method for `bar(s) within bar plot` construction method in ggplot2.

Example for two bars (group-wise division) within one bigger bar plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(40)
df <- data_frame(name = LETTERS[1:10], provision = rnorm(mean = 100, sd = 20, n = 10),
                expenditure = provision - rnorm(mean = 25, sd = 10, n = 10))

df %>% mutate(savings = provision - expenditure) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("expenditure", "savings"), names_to = "Exp", values_to = "val") %>%
  ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x= name, y = provision/2), stat = "identity", fill = "blue", width = 0.9, alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_col(aes(x=name,y=val, fill = Exp), position ="dodge", width = 0.7) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Amount in \u20b9")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option to overlay your bars without lowering transparency using `alpha` is to `group_by` the data based on your `fill` variable and `arrange(desc())` your `y` variable, using `position = position_identity()` to overlay your bars and have the highest value bars behind and lower values in front. Then you don't need to change the transparency. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
# Add name for fill aesthetic
dEQ$name <- "dEQ"
LMD$name <- "LMD"

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
dEQ %>%
  rbind(LMD) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  arrange(desc(perc)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = lab, y = perc, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_identity())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see the bars overlay while keeping the origin transparency.