# How to superpose barplots in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to superpose three barplots.

*Plot 1:*

[image: Plot 1]

*Plot 2:*

[image: Plot 2]

*Plot 3:*

[image: Plot 3]

```
fzg <- structure(list(start = c(40L, 22L, 37L, 32L, 72L, 41L, 2L, 11L, 57L, 10L, 102L, 40L, 17L, 48L, 86L, 46L, 49L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 13L, 69L, 42L, 31L, 39L, 64L, 39L, 29L, 67L, 5L, 1L, 54L, 32L, 7L, 4L, 67L, 14L, 26L, 20L, 42L, 26L, 57L, 0L, 34L, 114L), period = 1:45,     zug = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,     TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE,     FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,     FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,     TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,     TRUE), typ = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,     2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,     2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,     1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), dyn1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 203L, 0L, 0L, 0L,     111L, 0L, 112L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 191L, 0L, 95L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,     92L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 176L, 0L, 0L, 135L, 0L, 0L, 60L, 0L, 0L,     0L, 110L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 185L, 0L, 0L, 148L), dyn2 = c(0L,     0L, 0L, 0L, 203L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 223L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,     0L, 286L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 268L, 0L, 0L, 0L,     0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 305L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,     0L, 333L)), .Names = c("start", "period", "zug", "typ", "dyn1", "dyn2"), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = "data.frame")

x_scale_max <- max(fzg$start, fzg$dyn1, fzg$dyn2)

ggplot(fzg, aes(x=period, y=start, fill=typ)) +   geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + ylim(0,x_scale_max)
ggplot(fzg, aes(x=period, y=dyn1, fill=typ)) +   geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + ylim(0,x_scale_max)
ggplot(fzg, aes(x=period, y=dyn2, fill=typ)) +   geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+ ylim(0,x_scale_max)
```

The resulting barplot should

- show all the small bars from plot 1 in color 0
- show all the highlighted bars from plot 1 in color 1
- show the added portions from plot 2 in color 2
- show the added portions from plot 3 in color 3

I managed to get all in one plot

```
library(reshape2)
mdat <- melt(fzg[c("start", "period", "dyn1", "dyn2")], measured=c("start","dyn1","dyn2"), id="period")
ggplot(mdat, aes(x=period, y=value, fill=variable)) +   geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack") + ylim(0,x_scale_max)
```

But the color highlighting of the different steps does not work well.

Comment: You can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134605/how-to-overlay-two-geom-bar)

Comment: so is it necessary to split up the data.frame in as many data.frames as I want plots? Or is there a solution for one data.frame? (I guess, I can just copy and create several data.frames, it just doesn't seem very elegant to me, considering ggplot usually is fine with one data.frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for this
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwjPq.jpg)

Just modify your code :

```
mdat <- melt(fzg[c("start", "period", "dyn1", "dyn2", "typ")], measured=c("start","dyn1","dyn2"), id=c("period", "typ"))
mdat <- mdat[mdat$value != 0,]
ggplot(mdat, aes(x=period, y=value, fill=interaction(variable,typ))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```