# Nested ggplot histograms instead of cumulative

Tags: r, ggplot2

using this table :

```
  Groups variable value
1     G1     VAR1  75.0
2     G1     VAR2  37.5
3     G2     VAR1  50.0
4     G2     VAR2  12.5
```

and this code :

```
color_list <- c("VAR1"="blue","VAR2"="red")

tab %>%
  mutate(Groups = fct_reorder(Groups, value)) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=value, y=Groups,fill=factor(variable, levels = c("VAR1","VAR2")),label=Groups))  +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_list[unique(tab$variable)], guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +  theme_minimal()
```

I managed to get the following figure:
[image]

But here is what I expect :

[image]

As you can see it is rather a nested histogram I need instead of a cumulative histogram representation.

Does anyone have an idea how to do it using ggplot2?

Here is the table data in dput format if it can helps:

```
structure(list(Groups = c("G1", "G1", "G2", "G2"), variable = c("VAR1", 
"VAR2", "VAR1", "VAR2"), value = c(75, 37.5, 50, 12.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Somehow I'd expect a histogram to plot counts, not sure what a value of 37.5 could mean in that context. Could you confirm if it is really a histogram you want?

Comment: Sure, I edited the code. In fact I would simply like to plot the count for each variable Categories where VAR1 (blue) should be in background, and VAR2 (red) in forground.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134605/how-to-overlay-two-geom-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134605/how-to-overlay-two-geom-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, mixing up your code, the hints given by dario and something else:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

color_list <- c("VAR1"="blue","VAR2"="red")

tab %>%
  mutate(Groups = fct_reorder(Groups, value)) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = Groups, y = value, 
              fill  = factor(variable, levels = c("VAR1","VAR2")), 
              group = variable, 
              label = value)) +
  # here you overlap your bars
  geom_bar (stat="identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0)) +
  # here custom colors
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_list[unique(tab$variable)], 
                    guide  = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  # y (x) axis as you've pointed out, values and 30 by 30 labels, you can 
  # customize it of course
  scale_y_continuous("value", labels =c(seq(from = 0, to = 90, by = 30),tab$value), breaks = c(seq(from = 0, to = 90, by = 30),tab$value)) +  
  # some frills
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(fill = "title")
```

[image]