# How to combine multiple ggplot geom_col() into one graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

**Question**
I am trying to combine three ggplot `geom_bar` into one geom_bar plot utilising `dodge` so I can visually compare data across two categorical and one numeric variables. What am I doing wrong?

**Individual graphs work**
Each graph works on it's own (with formatting issues) and I've been following answers on SO like [How to overlay two geom_bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134605/how-to-overlay-two-geom-bar) but I'm not understanding what's needed to be done.

```
ONE <- ggplot(Ireland, aes(TargetGroup, FirstDosePC))+geom_bar(stat = 'identity',width = 0.8, fill = "green") + 
  facet_grid(.~Vaccine) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
  labs(title="1st Dose Ireland by Group & Vaccine Type", 
       caption = "(ECDC, 2021)",
       x="Target Groups over 18",
       y="First Dose Administered")

TWO <- ggplot(Italy, aes(TargetGroup, FirstDosePC))+ geom_bar(stat = 'identity',width = 0.8, fill = "blue") + 
  facet_grid(.~Vaccine) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
  labs(title="1st Dose Italy by Group & Vaccine Type", 
       caption = "(ECDC, 2021)",
       x="Target Groups over 18",
       y="First Dose Administered")

THREE <- ggplot(Latvia, aes(TargetGroup, FirstDosePC))+geom_bar(stat = 'identity',width = 0.8, fill = "red") + 
  facet_grid(.~Vaccine) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
  labs(title="1st Dose Latvia by Group & Vaccine Type", 
       caption = "(ECDC, 2021)",
       x="Target Groups over 18",
       y="First Dose Administered")
```

**An example of failed code**
My coding attempts look close to this but it seems to fail - I don't understand why. I am hoping to learn how to add three graphs together with labels and to use `dodge`

```
OneTwo <- ONE + geom_bar(FDPercent=Italy, aes(TargetGroup, FirstDose))+ geom_bar(stat = 'identity',width = 0.8, fill = "blue") + 
  facet_grid(.~Vaccine) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
  labs(title="1st Dose Italy by Group & Vaccine Type", 
       caption = "(ECDC, 2021)",
       x="Target Groups over 18",
       y="First Dose Administered")
```

**My individual graphs look like this**

[image: Sample from one of the graphs]

**The graph type I'm aiming for**
and what I am aiming for is something like this but breaking it out by vaccine type to stretch my learning, etc (source https://towardsdatascience.com/track-covid-19-data-yourself-with-r-eb3e641cd4b3)
[image: The goal]

**My raw data comes from**

```
data <- read.csv("https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/vaccine_tracker/csv/data.csv", na.strings = "", fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
```

and is manipulated to test out R functions that has left me with a dataframe called `FDPercent`  with a numeric column called `FirstDosePC` (Percentage of 1st Dose per country population) that is linked to `Country` with 30 EU countries (ISO 3166-1-alpha-2 categorical data) and 10 `TargetGroup` types (categorical) in the data frame.

```
> dput(head(FDPercent,3))
structure(list(Country = c("AT", "AT", "AT"), NumberDosesReceived = c(0L, 
0L, 61425L), NumberDosesExported = c(0L, 0L, 0L), FirstDose = c(0L, 
0L, 87L), FirstDoseRefused = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), SecondDose = c(0L, 0L, 0L), UnknownDose = c(0L, 0L, 0L), TargetGroup = c("Age18_24", 
"Age18_24", "Age18_24"), Vaccine = c("UNK", "AZ", "COM"), Population = c(8901064L, 
8901064L, 8901064L), Date = structure(c(18624, 18624, 18624), class = "Date"), 
    FirstDosePC = c("0.0000", "0.0000", "0.0010")), row.names = 21:23, class = "data.frame")
> str(FDPercent)
'data.frame':   116532 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ Country            : chr  "AT" "AT" "AT" "AT" ...
 $ NumberDosesReceived: int  0 0 61425 0 0 0 61425 0 0 0 ...
 $ NumberDosesExported: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FirstDose          : int  0 0 87 0 0 0 1299 0 0 0 ...
 $ FirstDoseRefused   : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ SecondDose         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ UnknownDose        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ TargetGroup        : chr  "Age18_24" "Age18_24" "Age18_24" "Age18_24" ...
 $ Vaccine            : chr  "UNK" "AZ" "COM" "MOD" ...
 $ Population         : int  8901064 8901064 8901064 8901064 8901064 8901064 8901064 8901064 8901064 8901064 ...
 $ Date               : Date, format: "2020-12-28" "2020-12-28" "2020-12-28" "2020-12-28" ...
 $ FirstDosePC        : chr  "0.0000" "0.0000" "0.0010" "0.0000" ...
```

Comment: Is something like patwork too complicated for this task? <https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork>

Comment: You can't stack the `gggplot()`, `theme()`, or `scale_`. You can only stack the `geom_`, `stat_`, or `annotate`. Alternatively, you could drop the separated datasets, using `filter()` before `ggplot()` and the `fill` or `group` arguments to separate or group the data.

Comment: @Kat thank you so try... ```ONE1 <- ggplot(Ireland, aes(TargetGroup, FirstDosePC))+geom_bar(stat = 'identity',width = 0.8, fill = "green") + 
  facet_grid(.~Vaccine)``` and then ```TWO2 <- ONE1 + geom_bar(FDPercent=Italy, 
        aes(Italy$TargetGroup, Italy$FirstDose))+ 
  facet_grid(.~Vaccine)``` is this any closer? There is an error ```Warning message:
Ignoring unknown parameters: FDPercent ```

Comment: When using a different dataset in the different calls to `geom_`, you either need to set the argument `data` or `mapping`. So for the call to Italy, write: `geom_col(data = Italy, aes(x = TargetGroup, y = FirstDose))` (Just thought I'd mention, think of `geom_bar()` as something for one variable and `geom_col()` for cases with both an x and y. No identity needed.)

Comment: Thank you @Kat New Year;s dinner burnt and family upset - but figured it out and buying thakeawy (sandwiches for the next few days!) Happy New Year!

Comment: Awesome! They can cook it if they don't like it :)

Answer (score 0):

With help from @kat in the comments - changed from `geom_bar()` to `geom_col()` and dropped the third variable

```
Ireland <- subset(FDPercent, Country == "IE") #contructed a subset by country
Italy <- subset(FDPercent, Country == "IT")
Latvia <- subset(FDPercent, Country == "LV")

ONE1 <- ggplot(Italy,  aes(Date, as.numeric(FirstDosePC))) +
  geom_col(fill = "red", alpha = 1, width = 7) +  theme_minimal(base_size = 8) +  
  xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL) + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y/%m/%d") #reduced the theme formating
OneTwo <- ONE1 + geom_col(data=Ireland,  aes(Date, 
    as.numeric(FirstDosePC)),  
    fill="Green",  alpha = 1,width = 5)
OneTwoThree <- OneTwo + geom_col(data=Latvia,  aes(Date, 
    as.numeric(FirstDosePC)),  
    fill="black",  alpha = 1, width = 2)
OneTwoThree + labs(title="Ireland, Italy, & Latvia - First Dose comparision", #added labels to the data
    subtitle="Using First Dose Delivered per day as a percentage of population",              
    caption = "(ECDC, 2021)",
    x="Date Administered",
    y="% Population treated")
```

[image: Combined three geom_col() plots into one plot]